# Написать функцию, которая делает GET-запрос к API и возвращает в консоль результаты с сервера

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

Подскажите как написать функцию — она делает GET-запрос к API, который указан в переменной URL и возвращает в консоль результаты с сервера, используя Fetch API. Важно: выведите в консоль именно массив с результатами, без самой информации о запросе. У меня проблема именно с выводом массива в консоль.

```
const URL = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';

async function request(url) {
  const data = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  console.log(data.results);
}

request(url);
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';
fetch(url)
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data.results[0]);
  });
```